# Showing null values for some of the Power BI rows

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have joined an excel sheet with the world population web link from Wikipedia in my Power BI tool. When I merge these two tables, it shows me the population only from the United States, other countries have null values.

Would really appreciate the help. Screenshots provided below

[image: Error]

[image: while merging]

Comment: For countries present in country population  and not present in cookies, null values will get populated

Comment: @AshokAnumula there are five matching countries in both country populations and cookies but it is still showing the null values. How can i resolve this?

Comment: @AshokAnumula I have used this web link to get the country populations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population

Comment: Only for those 5 matching countries you will get values. For all other countries you will get null values

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your merge isn't matching the rows as you expect.

I would try to investigate if there are "invisible" differences in the columnar values:

`Canada`  (with an appended space) will not match to `Canada` for example. To check for this, go into the table you are merging and select to `Trim` the key column.

In the table you are merging into, do the same `Trim` operation for the key column.

Edit: Another option is to apply fuzzy matching to the merging process and to limit the amount of fuzzyness by setting maximum number of matches per row and adjusting the similarity threshold up from 0.80 to something closer to the maximum 1.00 (= exact matching).

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is left join. Try with join tables with country column to present all columns.

Click dropdown and select full outer feature and expand.

Comment: I tried with a full outer join but the population values for countries other than the United States are null.